# How far do Jews have to be so they are Petur from sukkah

Tags: halacha, sukkah, sukkot, orach-chaim, petur-exemption

According to Halacha, on sukkot Jews  should eat whatever food they are going to eat in the sukkah. My question is, is there any length  Jews  have to be from a sukkah so they are  Petur from the obligation eat in it? What is the size of distance Jews have to travel that they don’t have to go out of their way to eat in the sukkah

Comment: Why travel to one? Just build one where you are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is less about the distance, and more about whether there is a good reason to travel knowing there won't be a sukkah.

Those who travel for pressing matters (business, mitzvah) are permitted to eat outside a sukkah during the day ([OC 640:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.640.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) if they don't find one. The same is true at night although they have to try hard.

There is a discussion in the poskim whether a day trip for fun is allowed should there be no sukkah.